# Pandas - select dataframe columns if statistic is greater than certain value

Tags: pandas, statistics, multiple-columns

I have pandas dataframe `df`. I would like to select columns which have standard deviation grater than 1. Here is what I tried

```
df2 = df[df.std() >1]
df2 = df.loc[df.std() >1]
```

Both generated error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to select from the row index, not the columns. Use instead: `df.loc[:, df.std() > 1]`

Comment: @ajcr Thank you very much, you answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.loc[:, df.std() > 1]` and it will fix it.

The first part which is `[:` refers to the rows and the second part `df.std() > 1` refers to the columns